# Upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04, no Sound anymore

Tags: drivers, nvidia, sound, pulseaudio, lxqt

Former Sw : Lubuntu 20.04, and the respective LXQT version. An update to Lubuntu 22.04 via DVD installation was not possible (failed to start snap daemon).

Another way used : Set SW sources -> upgrade -> normal, then I got Ubuntu 21.10.

Set SW sources -> upgrade back to -> LTS, then I got Ubuntu 22.04, the result (also the audio HW, and driver configuration, please see below)

```
uname -r
5.15.0-37-generic

lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy

LXQt About Version
0.17.0
LXQt Version
0.17.0
Qt
5.15.3
Build type
Release

hwinfo --sound
28: PCI 05.0: 0403 Audio device                                 
  [Created at pci.386]
  Unique ID: CvwD.v1n2PVq0Ow4
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:05.0
  SysFS BusID: 0000:00:05.0
  Hardware Class: sound
  Model: "nVidia MCP61 High Definition Audio"
  Vendor: pci 0x10de "nVidia Corporation"
  Device: pci 0x03f0 "MCP61 High Definition Audio"
  SubVendor: pci 0x1849 "ASRock Incorporation"
  SubDevice: pci 0x0397 
  Revision: 0xa2
  Driver: "snd_hda_intel"
  Driver Modules: "snd_hda_intel"
  Memory Range: 0xfbff8000-0xfbffbfff (rw,non-prefetchable)
  IRQ: 21 (40210 events)
  Module Alias: "pci:v000010DEd000003F0sv00001849sd00000397bc04sc03i00"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: snd_hda_intel is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe snd_hda_intel"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown

cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [NVidia         ]: HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia
                      HDA NVidia at 0xfbff8000 irq 21
```

All works fine, except I have no audio output anymore as on the Lubuntu 20.04 system.

I see the loudspeaker on panel as active, Pulse audio used as before.

I see Driver Info #0 :

"Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, **need=no, active=unknown**"

Is this the problem ? Does someone know where it is to config ?
Or if this is not the problem, has someone an idea, how I can find the error ?

Comment: Now found the problem : Installed pavucontrol, called it and there : Port setting was Headphones, I did change it to LineOut (indicated as connected), and now it works. "need=no, active=unknown" see above, is the same as before, so it was OK. Obviously during upgrade to 22.04 the settings will be changed.

Answer (score 0):

I had no sound output options after upgrading to ubuntu 22.04 (not even Dummy Output), and pavucontrol was stuck at "Establishing connection to PulseAudio..". The following solved the issue for me:

`pulseaudio --check`

`pulseaudio -D`